# Sceneform - Getting Vector3 position from screen pixel position?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

The Sceneform camera has the `camera.setWorldPosition` method which accepts a `Vector3`.

I have currently calculated the center point of where the user `pinches` the screen  using the `ScaleGestureDetector`.

My question is, how can I calculate the `Vector3` position I want to move to based a single point on the screen?

Let's say the user pinches near the middle of the screen --- the ratio for the X and Y coordinates calculated from the phone's display metrics are

`X: 0.58122176, Y: 0.46196362`

How do I convert it into a `Vector3` so my SceneView `camera` can zoom in that position on the screen?

```
 private class ZoomGestureDetector extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            
            float ratioX = detector.getFocusX() / displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            float ratioY = detector.getFocusY() / displayMetrics.heightPixels;

            Log.d(TAG, "onScale: Called X: " + ratioX + ", Y: " + ratioY);

            Camera camera = sceneView.getScene().getCamera();
            //camera.setWorldPosition(); <--- How to calculate vector3

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            isScaling = true;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            isScaling = false;

        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

Essentially I'm trying to get the camera to zoom in/out where I'm pinching on the screen.

Is this not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to convert a 2d point into a 3d point, the depth needs to be added. This is done by creating a Ray from the camera through the point. To get the Vector3, a distance along that ray is picked.

For example, in [DrawingActivity](https://github.com/googlesamples/sceneform-samples/blob/master/drawing/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/drawing/DrawingActivity.java), the screen tap is used to create the ray, then a Vector3 is created `DRAW_DISTANCE` from the camera.

```
MotionEvent tap;
Camera camera = fragment.getArSceneView().getScene().getCamera();
Ray ray = camera.screenPointToRay(tap.getX(), tap.getY());
Vector3 drawPoint = ray.getPoint(DRAW_DISTANCE);
```

You'll need to decide on a value for DRAW_DISTANCE based on your specific use case. (DRAW_DISTANCE will get smaller as you zoom).

You can look at [ScaleGestureDetector](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale#basic-scaling-example) to handle the pinch and stretch gestures.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help. Also appreciate the link to the ScaleGestureDetector page -- that was the next thing I was planning to do!